# WooCommerce, change the term "order" to "donation"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have found many filters and plugins to allow the changing of default terminology in WooCommerce, but I can't find anything relating to the term "order".

I am building a non-profit site that accepts "donations". How can I change the term "order" to "donations".

It appears all over woocom including mails.

Comment: i think you cannot change this term by a simple filter, as you said it's present in many places so you need to handle all these places one by one

Comment: You could probably filter `woocommerce_register_post_type_shop_order` and change all the labels. Or you could use a plugin like Charitable or Give to handle donations specifically.